# Why do the giant armors bleed when cut?

Tags: nobunaga-the-fool

Although I am not sure if this also happened in earlier episodes, as I did not really pay attention to it, I couldn't help but notice that in episode 14 during the battle, Nobunaga's armor started bleeding after getting cut.

Why and how did the armors bleed? Did this happen in earlier episodes as well?